# Comment displayed backwards in apps

Tags: bug, comments, android-app, ios-app, russian-stackoverflow

[The comment](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5362/%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0/5365#comment20007_5365) displayed backwards in the iOS app:

> [image: ios]

In web it looks correctly:

> [image: web]

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.2 (Build 14F89)

Same for Android app:

> [image: android]

- App Version: 1.0.94
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 7.0 (1710300506712)

As far as I understand this comment contains text direction symbols. More info can be obtained from [chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37849132#37849132).

Comment: I can reproduce this using the iOS app (backwards) and browser (Chrome; forwards) app on my iPhone.

Comment: We're not alone in our confusion: https://i.stack.imgur.com/miHUQ.png