# LTR and RTL nicknames mixture produces a messed up stream of characters (+ proposal of a hack to fix it)

Tags: bug, design, rtl

*Note: I am aware that this issue was reported many times for at least 9 years. However, it is still not fixed, and I created a hack to fix it.*

Just for fun, I rendered my nickname in NKo script that happens to be RTL one.

However, RTL nicknames make havoc being composed into a list along with LRT ones. 
For example, [a question where I cast a close vote](http://web.archive.org/web/20190619112104/https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/993370/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5-gui-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-java-swing)<sup>[*archived*]</sup> got the following note and [a history entry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/993370/revisions#spacer-69abe1cb-777d-483b-8072-cd238cccf242):

[image]

[image]

Notice that a nickname `0xdb` was broken into two parts, interleaved with my nickname, as well as its comma.

**A hack:**

HTML markup shows that two names are wrapped into their own `<a>` tags:

[image]

By default, `<a>` tags are inline, so they do not affect rendering. **However, when I turned links into isolated blocks via `display: inline-block`, it broke a character stream and fixed the issue:**

[image]

Unfortunately, this hack helps only in places where inline wrappers are used. To properly fix the issue, U+200F RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK and U+200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK need to be inserted when script direction change is detected.

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296726/339911