# Unable to run iOS app on iPadOS 14.5

Tags: support, ios-app, ipad

After upgrading my iPad to iPadOS 14.5, the Stack Exchange app became nonrunnable.

> [image: Unable to run SE app]

I know that mobile apps are not maintained now, but could you please fix this major issue to make the app at least runnable?

It looks even weirder, but notifications from the app still work:

> [image: Notification]

Comment: Why don't you use the website? I think this will get [tag:status-declined] very quickly.

Comment: The apps have been formally removed from the stores and there is no chance any update will ever happen to them.

Comment: I updated to iOS 14.5 yesterday and it's still working ...

Comment: tbh - at this point a better bet might be to lobby for 'missing' features, primarily notifications and/or look at alternatives (and the required APIs to make them).

Comment: @Glorfindel what type of device you're using? Mine iPad Pro 10.5

Comment: [This one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad_Pro_(1st_generation))

Comment: @Glorfindel next question: what's the app version? I have 1.6.6 (according [this method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/97011/263093) since I can't see the version inside app itself for obvious reason).

Comment: Same version as you ...

Comment: @Glorfindel it seems that I have to buy your iPad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few days ago I have tried to launch the app again, and the popup similar to the following was appearing:

> [image: Needs to be updated popup]

I have pressed “Update” and voila.. App is working again.

It seems that despite absence of the app in the AppStore app developers have updated something to make the app work again.

My current iPadOS version is 14.6. Stack Exchange app version is 1.6.6.2 ([same as long time ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296726/339911)).

> [image: About SE app]

Comment: I find this highly unlikely. I have more faith in this to be due to random chance then to SE fixing anything with the app, as they have explicitly stated, on multiple occasions, that they won't be doing anything on the apps.